# Django: Context processors for error pages (or request in simple_tag)

Tags: python, django

In my Django project, there are several django apps. I want to write custom error pages, and I want them to contain correct links to the application that the errors happened in, for example, if a 500-error happened in my app `a`, I want the error page contain a link to `/a/index.html`, and if a server error happened in app `b`, I want the page to contain the link to `/b/index.html`. And I want to create only one copy of each of the error page files, which means I need to get the name of the app from within the template.

To that end, I have written a custom context processor that adds the `app_name` var to the templates. I tested it on my normal pages, but when I went on to test it on the error pages, turns out that the context processor isn't firing.

Similarly, I have written a template tag `app_aware_url` which takes the name of the url pattern and tries to resolve it, but again, turns out that for the error pages the `simple_tag(takes_context=True)` receives a context that does not contain the request (which is needed for telling which app I am in).

Is there a way round it, or is there a better solution to my problem altogether?

(Django is 1.11)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this seems to be a [custom error handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views).  The documentation on this is a bit...  Light?  So I had to do some experimentation to get it to work.

It turns out that that's only possible to do globally, in your base `urls.py`, so you can't have a custom one for a specific app, (which is sad), but you *can* work out the app from the request.

In your base [`urls.py`](https://github.com/Asday/django-custom-error-handler/blob/b638f876fd6531acd64061221178126eb030745a/config/urls.py#L19):

```
from .views import ErrorHandler


handler500 = lambda request: ErrorHandler.as_view()(request)
```

This will now defer to [`views.ErrorHandler`](https://github.com/Asday/django-custom-error-handler/blob/b638f876fd6531acd64061221178126eb030745a/base/views.py#L4) on every 500 that happens:

```
class ErrorHandler(TemplateView):
    template_name = '500.html'

    def get_app_name(self):
        module = self.request.resolver_match.func.__module__
        app, *path = module.split('.')

        return app

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        context['app_name'] = self.get_app_name()

        return context
```

Here, `.get_app_name()` is doing the magic.  It inspects the request's `resolver_match` - it's path through the `urls` machinery, and determines which app it was in based on that.

From here, the sky's the limit.  I simply subclassed `TemplateView` for easiness' sake, but you can defer to `django.views.defaults.server_error()` if you want.  Whatever your heart desires.

If you wanna get more hands-on, I've thrown together a [repo](https://github.com/Asday/django-custom-error-handler/), (commit [b638f8](https://github.com/Asday/django-custom-error-handler/tree/b638f876fd6531acd64061221178126eb030745a) at the time of writing), which you can feel free to check out and much around with.

Comment: Sorry, we ended up removing this from our project. I will try to test your approach later. If it does work, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may step on the same rakes: 
What I ended up doing is passing the "app_name" variable from the error page views to the context. Thus the variable is in the context for non-error pages, because it is set by the context processor, and it is there for error pages because it is passed manually. Doesn't look like a good solution though.